Getting HTTPS for elastic beanstal single instance
I am a little confused about setting up HTTPS for single-instance Elastic Beanstalk. I understand I must configure the nginx\conf.d\https.conf file to point to the certificate and key files. However, Squarespace issued my certificate and key for my domain. I could easily download the certificate from the browser but couldn't get the key from them. So should I create a certificate through Amazon using my key or is there anything that I am missing?

I think SquareSpace certificates only work with SquareSpace sites. It doesn't look like they let you download the private key. It's the same with AWS certificates, they only work with AWS load balancers, CloudFront, and API Gateway. With a single EC2 instance environment without a load balancer, you will have to use something like Lets Encrypt to generate a certificate that you can use with Nginx.
It's much easier to use a load balancer in your environment, and attach an AWS SSL certificate to that load balancer, but of course you have to pay for the load balancer.
